# Как запрограммировать кнопки для управления игроком

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, разработка-игр

Делал игру (runner), в Unity, на языке C#, по обучающему видео, но мне нужно, чтобы игра была с управлением под телефон, для этого я решил сделать управление с помощью кнопок (Up и Down), потому, что персонаж реагировал только на нажатие стрелок на клавиатуре, но я не понимаю как написать script который позволял бы, через нажатие на ту или иную кнопку поднимать вверх или опускать вниз игрока, а также на какой объект потом вешать этот script.

Если что, вот script игрока (Player):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 targetPos;
    public float Yincrement;

    public float speed;
    public float maxHeight;
    public float minHeight;

    public int health = 3;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
        {
            targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Yincrement);

        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > minHeight)
        {
            targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Yincrement);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вынести `targetPos =...`  в отдельные публичные функции и указать в компоненте кнопки на них